# Azure DevOps - Disable project access for specific members of an AD group in a project team

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2019

I am using Azure DevOps On Prem Version 2020. We have a project(xyz) with one of the team having an Active Directory ( AD ) group. **We want to disable access to the project(xyz) for few members of the Active Directory group .** **Is it doable ? even though the AD group has contributor access**.

we want to overide the contributor access for few specific members of the AD group . we do not want to delete the members from the AD group because the same AD group is used in different project.

Comment: I just asked a colleague and he told me that you might need to create another specific AD group for them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically it's possible to use deny rules to block the other members. But you will need to do it at every level where more specific authorizations were given.

At the location where your contributors group have been granted permissions, configure a 2nd permission that explicitly sets sets the rule to Deny.